# How to sum audio from two streams in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file with two audio streams, representing two people talking at different times.  The two people never talk at the same time, so there is no danger of clipping by summing the audio.  I would like to sum the audio into one stream without reducing the volume.  The ffmpeg [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter has an option that would seem to do what I want, but the option does not seem to work.  Here are two minimal non-working examples (the audio tracks are [0:2] and [0:3]):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -c:v copy \
       -filter_complex '[0:2][0:3]amix' \
       output.m4v

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -c:v copy \
       -filter_complex '[0:2][0:3]amix=sum=sum' \
       output.m4v
```

The first example diminishes the audio volume.  The second example is a syntax error.  I tried other variants like `amix=sum` and `amix=sum=1`, but despite the documentation I don't think the sum option exists any more.  `ffmpeg -h filter=amix` does not mention the sum option (ffmpeg version n4.3.1).

My questions:

1. Can I sum two audio tracks with ffmpeg, without losing resolution.  (I'd rather not cut the volume in half and scale it up, but if there's no other way I guess I'd accept and answer that sacrifices a bit.)
2. Is there an easy way to adjust the relative delay of one of the tracks by a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` option was added on 2021-02-04, so it's not in any release yet. You'll to have a use current **git** build.

To add a delay, use the adelay filter.

Suppose, you wanted to delay the first audio by 50ms,

```
-filter_complex '[0:2]adelay=50:all=1[a1];[a1][0:3]amix=sum=sum'
```